# Scala/Play/Nginx: static resource routing

Tags: scala, nginx, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I've got my Play app running:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

Nginx is proxy passing it to this url:

```
http://localhost/Demo/
```

I have a problem with static assets though. For instance, this asset in html template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

is going to

```
http://localhost/assets/stylesheets/main.css
```

and obviously results in not being found. If I change it to this (add `/Demo` in front of the url):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/Demo@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

it will now correctly go to this url:

```
http://localhost/Demo/assets/stylesheets/main.css
```

My question is: how can I add this `/Demo` to all my static assets without hard codding it into my templates? I prefer to solve this using Play's routing and limit changes done to nginx conf.

I've tried adding a url prefix into `application.conf` like this

```
application.context="/Demo"
```

but that affected all urls not only the static ones, so not a solution. Any thoughts?

My stack:
Play Framework 2.2.1 /
Scala 2.10.3 /
Java 8 64bit /
Nginx 1.4.3 /
Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

**UPDATE: SOLUTION** Thanks to @biesior for providing the Java version, I've converted it to scala:

```
package core

import controllers.routes

object Assets {

    def at(path: String): String = {
        "/Demo" + routes.Assets.at(path)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the route `GET /Demo/assets/*file Assets.at("public", file)` and read the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/Assets)?

Comment: @krivachy.akos Yes and yes. Adding `/Demo` to routes results in all assets 404ing. The only way it works if I append it in templates.

Comment: Does it work without nginx? Do you think it's specific to that? I tried it out on one of my local Play apps and this worked nicely: `GET /Demo/assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`. Meaning my pages had: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">` and resulted in: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/Demo/assets/stylesheets/main.css">`

Comment: @krivachy.akos it does work without nginx whether I add `/Demo` or not (no change), but that is not the issue. I need it to work under Nginx and it does work if I edit the template URLs - all I want is one place to do this that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwite the path using own implementation of assets (ie. in `utils` package):

```
package utils;
import controllers.routes;

public class MyAssets {
    public static String at(String path){
        return "/Demo"+ routes.Assets.at(path).toString();
    }
}
```

in templates:

```
<img src='@utils.MyAssets.at("images/logo.png")' alt="">
```

On the quite other hand, will target project also work in subdirectory ? If not it's just easier to use subdomains, it's possible also with localhost, just configure your nginx for that project to use ie.: `http://demo.loc` instead od `http://localhost/Demo` and add this *'domain'* to your `hosts` file

Comment: Thanks, this is working, I've converted it to Scala though, that's what I'm working with on my project with.

Comment: Deal with others with Scala sample then pls ;)